Refresh issue of the script
I need accordion menu in the mobile devices (below 991px screens) and using bootstrap, it works good in desktop which is normal simple menu i.e. opening sub-menu on hover of the parent link, but on mobile  i need the sub-menu opening and closing like the accordion, i have achieve this using a little script but

While refreshing in the desktop and resizing the browser below 991px the sub-menu is not visible in the menu,
After refreshing in the mobile screen (below 991px) it will be there.
So i need the script to work on single refresh whether it's desktop or mobile, menu of the sub-menu in the mobile should work within a single refresh no matter where we have refresh the screen on mobile or desktop. I have also tried mathchMedia but it is not working so i have removed it from the example. I have created following link in the codepen for the reference,

codepen (https://codepen.io/Akash_Ramani/pen/jOjYYJz)
The following is the code.


$(document).ready(function($){
// Show/hide the main navigation
$(".navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children").append('<span class="collased-icon"></span>');
$(".navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children > .collased-icon").on("click",function() {
    $(this).prev(".sub-menu").slideToggle(350);
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 991 && $('.sub-menu').is(':hidden')) {  
        $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');  
    }  
});  
});
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fbf9ec;
}
header .container-fluid {
  padding: 0 120px;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1045;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #000;
}
#navbarNav.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-brand svg {
  transition: 0.4s;
  fill: #fff;
  width: 220px;
  height: auto;
}
.navbar-brand svg:hover {
  fill: #febf01;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.navbar-brand img:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(175deg);
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
  gap: 20px;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > li:hover > a.nav-link,
.navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-nav > li.current-menu-item > a,
.navbar-nav > li.current-menu-parent > a,
.navbar-nav > li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
.navbar-nav > li.current_page_parent > a,
.navbar-nav > li > a.nav-link.active {
  color: #febf01;
}
.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li a:hover,
.navbar-nav > li ul.sub-menu li:hover > a,
.navbar-nav > li ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-item > a,
.navbar-nav > li ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #d09c00 0%, #000 100%);
  color: #032647;
}
.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000 0%, #d09c00 100%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 238px;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 5px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: translate(0, 5px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in, transform 200ms ease-in,
    visibility 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in, transform 200ms ease-in,
    visibility 200ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in, transform 200ms ease-in,
    visibility 200ms ease-in;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 20px) rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 20px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: translate(0, 20px) rotateX(0deg);
  pointer-events: all;
}
.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li > a.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-nav
  > li.menu-item-has-children:hover
  > .sub-menu
  li.menu-item-has-children:hover
  > .sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  pointer-events: all;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff87;
}
.navbar-nav > li ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  right: 15px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
button.close-btn {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1599px) {
  header .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 90px;
  }
  .navbar-brand svg {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  header .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  header .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .navbar-brand svg {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    gap: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #473303 0%, #febf01 50%, #473303 100%);
    border: 0 solid transparent;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-size: auto 200%;
  }
  .navbar-toggler:hover {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-toggler .navbar-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .navbar-toggler .navbar-line + .navbar-line {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  .collapse:not(.show) {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 260px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #fcbd01 0%, #000 100%);
    left: -360px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    height: 100% !important;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .navbar .collapse.show {
    left: 0;
  }
  ul.navbar-nav {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    gap: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #313131 0%, #ca9700 100%);
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: initial;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu li > a.nav-link {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: initial;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li + li {
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff54;
  }
  .navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children > a {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children span.collased-icon {
    position: absolute;
    content: "+";
    color: #fff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: grab;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #473303 0%, #febf01 50%, #473303 100%);
    /* background-size: auto; */
    padding: 4px 8px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-size: auto 200%;
  }
  .navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children span.collased-icon:hover {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-nav
    > li.menu-item-has-children:hover
    > .sub-menu
    li.menu-item-has-children:hover
    > .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu li a.nav-link {
    padding: 11px 30px;
  }
  .navbar-nav
    > li.menu-item-has-children
    .sub-menu
    .sub-menu
    .sub-menu
    li
    a.nav-link {
    padding: 11px 40px;
  }
  .navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children span.collased-icon::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: 0.3s;
    top: 12px;
  }
  .navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children span.collased-icon.expand::before {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
    top: 18px;
  }
  button.close-btn {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #e0a801;
    border: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  button.close-btn span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #443312;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  button.close-btn span svg {
    fill: #fbf9ec;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  header .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
  .navbar-brand svg {
    width: 140px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a.nav-link {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fbf9ec;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 35px;
  }
}
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/fbVfPpyv/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-line"></span><span class="navbar-line"></span><span class="navbar-line"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
          <button class="close-btn">Close <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                <g>
                  <path d="M506.134,241.843c-0.006-0.006-0.011-0.013-0.018-0.019l-104.504-104c-7.829-7.791-20.492-7.762-28.285,0.068 c-7.792,7.829-7.762,20.492,0.067,28.284L443.558,236H20c-11.046,0-20,8.954-20,20c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20h423.557 l-70.162,69.824c-7.829,7.792-7.859,20.455-0.067,28.284c7.793,7.831,20.457,7.858,28.285,0.068l104.504-104 c0.006-0.006,0.011-0.013,0.018-0.019C513.968,262.339,513.943,249.635,506.134,241.843z"></path>
                </g>
              </svg></span></button>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item menu-item-has-children"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item menu-item-has-children"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.1</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item  menu-item-has-children"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.2</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.2.1</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.2.2</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.2.3</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.2.4</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.3</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 2.4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 3</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 4</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 5</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Service 6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




Please make the snippet into a proper runnable snippet rather than require people to go to the external site, thanks. Also, could you outline what debugging you have tried?

I do not understand the problem: if I execute the embedded script, the menu is visible and the submenu work, so what's wrong?

It's a script issues, if you refresh the page in the desktop the submenu will work nicely, it open all the way to the last submenu BUT without refreshing the page if you decrease the screen size to 991px, a mobile menu will open, in that menu you can not open the submenu, BUT if you again refresh the page in 991px and try to open the submenu it will open, so need this script work without refreshing the page.

@AHaworth, I have tried following code to achieve my purpose to not to refresh the page to open the submenu after i resize the screen to 991px,
var s = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)"); mobFunction(s); s.addListener(mobFunction); function mobFunction(s) {     $(".navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children").append('<span class="collased-icon"></span>');     $(".navbar-nav li.menu-item-has-children > .collased-icon").on("click",function() {             $(this).prev(".sub-menu").slideToggle(350);             $(this).toggleClass("expand");         }     ); }

Finally solved the issue myself and uploaded to the example above by using $(window).resize(function()  function Which i want to remove the inline style from the sub-menu when it return to the desktop screen (width more then 991px).

I had a website with the same issue: the phone screen would work fine in general but if i tried to resize the browser on my desktop, it wouldn't unless i refreshed. But never had a problem on my phone. My point is, it probably works just fine on phone screens too just chokes when in browser.

try the script above in the example, it works fine and was tried for few days, just replace the class to your class names @Annie
